# ST_ASMVTGEOM returning null for small complex polygons at low zoom

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have polygons that have around 150 ft2 area (according to `ST_Area`) and I'm having problems getting an MVT geometry from them.

They are pretty complex as you can see, many points as they are actually round shaped.

Here is one of the polygons in question

```
POLYGON ((-8190418.723850934 5702989.107844456, -8190418.976675798 5702989.350142421, -8190419.2410461195 5702989.579702175, -8190419.516325004 5702989.7959706485, -8190419.801849301 5702989.998426862, -8190420.096931133 5702990.18658305, -8190420.400859627 5702990.359985957, -8190420.712902597 5702990.518217821, -8190421.032308306 5702990.660897439, -8190421.358307255 5702990.787681113, -8190421.690114113 5702990.8982633585, -8190422.02692951 5702990.992377827, -8190422.3679420315 5702991.069797751, -8190422.712330138 5702991.1303366255, -8190423.059264166 5702991.173848612, -8190423.407908342 5702991.200228876, -8190423.757422721 5702991.209413872, -8190424.106965298 5702991.201381484, -8190424.455694008 5702991.1761510335, -8190424.802768711 5702991.13378333, -8190425.147353284 5702991.074380446, -8190425.488617589 5702990.998085456, -8190425.825739483 5702990.90508218, -8190426.157906814 5702990.795594684, -8190426.48431935 5702990.669886728, -8190426.804190753 5702990.528261143, -8190427.1167504005 5702990.371059119, -8190427.421245321 5702990.198659391, -8190427.71694196 5702990.011477263, -8190428.003127951 5702989.809963703, -8190428.279113848 5702989.594604139, -8190428.544234774 5702989.365917422, -8190428.797852033 5702989.124454481, -8190429.039354638 5702988.870796997, -8190429.268160798 5702988.605556087, -8190429.48371928 5702988.329370725, -8190429.685510791 5702988.042906264, -8190429.873049202 5702987.746852829, -8190430.04588273 5702987.441923642, -8190430.203594976 5702987.128853305, -8190430.345806025 5702986.808396048, -8190430.472173261 5702986.481323854, -8190430.582392271 5702986.148424676, -8190430.676197521 5702985.81050052, -8190430.753363023 5702985.468365461, -8190430.813702896 5702985.122843731, -8190430.857071755 5702984.774767715, -8190430.8833651515 5702984.424975979, -8190430.892519712 5702984.074311202, -8190430.8845134135 5702983.723618147, -8190430.8593655275 5702983.373741683, -8190430.817136645 5702983.02552468, -8190430.757928502 5702982.67980602, -8190430.681883743 5702982.337418581, -8190430.589185554 5702981.999187201, -8190430.480057265 5702981.665926708, -8190430.354761778 5702981.338439955, -8190430.213600938 5702981.017515875, -8190430.056914826 5702980.7039276, -8190429.88508089 5702980.398430617, -8190429.698513119 5702980.101760851, -8190429.497660967 5702979.814633048, -8190429.28300829 5702979.537738898, -8190429.055072214 5702979.271745457, -8190428.814401869 5702979.0172935175, -8190428.561577026 5702978.77499612, -8190428.297206785 5702978.545436913, -8190428.021928031 5702978.329168982, -8190427.736403925 5702978.126713305, -8190427.441322337 5702977.938557606, -8190427.137394122 5702977.765155178, -8190426.825351486 5702977.606923764, -8190426.505946155 5702977.4642445445, -8190426.179947605 5702977.337461266, -8190425.848141194 5702977.226879346, -8190425.511326277 5702977.132765166, -8190425.170314266 5702977.055345489, -8190424.825926683 5702976.994806791, -8190424.478993189 5702976.951294952, -8190424.130349573 5702976.924914762, -8190423.780835749 5702976.915729797, -8190423.431293727 5702976.923762155, -8190423.082565574 5702976.948992519, -8190422.735491405 5702976.991360092, -8190422.390907355 5702977.050762801, -8190422.049643561 5702977.127057545, -8190421.712522148 5702977.220060519, -8190421.380355262 5702977.32954769, -8190421.053943137 5702977.455255284, -8190420.7340721125 5702977.596880456, -8190420.4215127975 5702977.7540820185, -8190420.117018168 5702977.926481283, -8190419.821321762 5702978.113662904, -8190419.535135961 5702978.315175945, -8190419.259150208 5702978.530534952, -8190418.99402936 5702978.759221121, -8190418.7404121235 5702979.000683512, -8190418.498909498 5702979.254340432, -8190418.270103262 5702979.519580794, -8190418.0545446435 5702979.795765614, -8190417.852752943 5702980.0822295565, -8190417.665214287 5702980.378282482, -8190417.492380479 5702980.683211191, -8190417.334667902 5702980.996281077, -8190417.192456485 5702981.31673792, -8190417.066088826 5702981.643809736, -8190416.955869371 5702981.976708573, -8190416.862063642 5702982.314632455, -8190416.784897639 5702982.656767267, -8190416.724557243 5702983.002288822, -8190416.681187838 5702983.35036469, -8190416.654893894 5702983.700156336, -8190416.645738768 5702984.050821097, -8190416.653744511 5702984.401514167, -8190416.678891851 5702984.751390718, -8190416.721120187 5702985.099607867, -8190416.780327806 5702985.445326699, -8190416.856372066 5702985.7877143845, -8190416.949069766 5702986.125946051, -8190417.058197609 5702986.45920687, -8190417.183492683 5702986.786694001, -8190417.324653144 5702987.107618493, -8190417.481338933 5702987.4212072175, -8190417.6531725805 5702987.726704695, -8190417.839740106 5702988.02337495, -8190418.040592081 5702988.310503287, -8190418.255244625 5702988.58739798, -8190418.4831806095 5702988.853391967, -8190418.723850934 5702989.107844456))
```

And the geometry passed in the second argument for bounds:

```
POLYGON ((-8766409.899970295 5635549.221409475, -8766409.899970295 6261721.357121639, -8140237.7642581295 6261721.357121639, -8140237.7642581295 5635549.221409475, -8766409.899970295 5635549.221409475))
```

So the call looks like:

```
ST_ASMVTGEOM(<polygon mentioned above>,<bounds mentioned above>,4096, 256, true)
```

I'm basically trying to see a small polygon from up high but that's not working.

But when passing these bounds (small area, closer zoom), the method returns a geometry:

```
POLYGON ((-8218509.281222152 5635549.221409475, -8218509.281222152 5713820.738373496, -8140237.7642581295 5713820.738373496, -8140237.7642581295 5635549.221409475, -8218509.281222152 5635549.221409475))
```

Is there anything I can do to see these shapes from a lower zoom level ?